# Cartoon where dream-people realize they are dreamed, travel to real world to bring dreamer into it (while keeping him asleep)

Tags: identify-this-movie

I once saw this cartoon as a kid, and it seems a lot cooler when I think back upon it. In the cartoon, there are scientists that are looking through telescopes and somehow figure out that the world they are in is in someone's dream. If the dreamer awakes, their entire world will disappear. They are able to make a portal into the real world, basically into the bedroom of the dreamer. They find him sleeping, put pillows around the alarm clock, carefully move his bed back through the portal (into his own dream), and then secure him in a very quiet padded room.

Then the idea was he would never awake and their world would continue to exist. I'm not sure on this, but I don't think there were any words spoken in it; the characters were able to explain it with though bubbles and emoting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [Rarg](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0216140/combined) from 1988.

> The plot revolves about the kingdom of Rarg which the chief scientists discover that Rarg is in fact someone's dream and that soon the person dreaming will wake up. So they try their best to stop him waking up.

They invent a portal, reach the sleeping man through it and stop his alarm clock from ringing (with their pillow-like bodies) and then secure him in a padded room. But unfortunately, the man starts dreaming about flamingos in the end, which they all then suddenly turn into... The short is available on Youtube.

[image]